# Codeigniter loading wrong class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant seem to load `application/model/Event.php` model class then access a method from it.
Instead CI loads **application/core/App_loader.php** and tries to look for the method there.

Can anyone lend a hand on how to fix this please?

In: **application/config/config.php**

```
//$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'App_';
```

Event.php

```
class Event extends CI_Model {

  private $db_main;

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db_main = $this->load->database('main', TRUE);
  }

   function get($arr = array()) {
    // ! Trying to access this method ...
   }
}
```

From controller I am trying to load a model class called Event (verified that function index() gets called): `application/controller/home.php`

```
class Home extends App_Controller {

  private $event;

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->event = $this->load->model('Event');
  }

  function index() {
    $this->method1();
  }

  function method1() {
     $eventArr = $this->event->get(); // << Cant access method
  }
```

`Message: Call to undefined method App_Loader::get()`

inside **application/core/App_loader.php**:

```
class App_Loader extends CI_Loader {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function aa(){}
  function bb(){}
  function cc(){}
}
```

Comment: use $this->load->model('event'); instead of $this->load->model('Event');

Comment: that gives me `Message: Cannot access private property Home::$event` `Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\system\core\Loader.php`

Comment: no need to create a variable $event, you can just load a model like $this->load->model('Event'); which makes available to use model methods directly using variable $this->event->get(); REFER LINK: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: when I comment out `//private $event;` on top and load model `$this->load->model('Event');` then try to access method `$this->event->get(); `  I get an error `Message: Undefined property: Home::$event`

Comment: try changing $this->load->model('Event'); to $this->load->model('event'); because CI documentation too shows, while accessing model name they are using model name in lower case.

Comment: @PrasadWargad If you sum this up I will accept this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference taken from https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model

```
class Event extends CI_Model {

    private $db_main;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db_main = $this->load->database('main', TRUE);
    }

    function get($arr = array()) {
        // ! Trying to access this method ...
    }
}

class Home extends App_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('event');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->method1();
    }

    function method1() {
        $eventArr = $this->event->get();
    }
}
```